# How to synchronize two UIDatePickers

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I have two (2) UIDatePickers in my iPad app (XCode 4.5, Storyboards, iOS 6.0).  One UIDatePicker is used for a "start" date/time, the other is for "end" time (does not show the date, just the time).

I want to be able to set the second picker ("end" time) **date** to equal what was selected in the "start" date/time picker.

I have looked in Google and SO, and can find nothing.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If on different view and controller then you need to pass the `date` to other class.
For this you can use a delegate or notification.

and then use something like this

Use `[secondDatePicker setDate:firstDatePicker.date]`

If both are on same controller then, you can simply add an action method as :

```
- (IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)picker {
  _secondDatePicker.date = picker.date;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both... they are basically the same answer, given at the same time... I picked Anoop's only because I already had the -IBAction.  Thanks again...

Comment: @spokane-dude : here nothing to earn!! I joined SO for learning purpose... these numbers and reputations will not count i guess, Till date I havent seen any one mentioning this SO in his CV. I hope some day I will see and will mention :)

Answer (score 1):

Add an action handler for ValueChanged event of the first datePicker and when its value changes, apply it to the second picker.

```
- (IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)picker {
  self.secondPicker.date = picker.date;
}
```